# android RTP send and receive program

Tags: android, audio, rtp

I am new to android programming and i need idea about android RTP programming stuff. Questions

1. How to capture the microphone audio data on android device?
2. How to construct RTP packet by using captured microphone audio data **without using API**?
3. How to transmit RTP packet to other android device?
4. How to play received RTP packet in android ?

Answer (score 2):

For transmitting and receiving RTP packets, I would suggest looking into the [jlibrtp library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibrtp/).  Basically you initialize it with 2 DatagramSockets (one for sending RTP data and one for receiving RTCP data), define a payload type, add a recipient, and send byte arrays.  I beleive it handles the RTP timestamps by itself, but you have to make sure you're payload is already formatted by the RFC reccommendations.

[Here is an example of how you would set up an RTP session](http://jlibrtp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jlibrtp/jlibrtp/demo/org/jlibrtp/demo/UnicastExample.java?revision=249&view=markup)

Answer (score 1):

Answers for your questions..

1.Use Android Media Api like `AudioRecord` for `recording` the voice data & `AudioTrack` for `playing` the voice data, both in .pcm format.

2.Go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html)

3.you have to use `sip` for transmiting packets.

4.go through this [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2012-01/msg00008.html)